# How to implement a dynamic-size hash table?

Tags: data-structures, hashtable

I know the basic principle of the hash table data structure. If I have a hash table of size N, I have to distribute my data into these N buckets as evenly as possible.

But in reality, most languages have their built-in hash table types. When I use them, I don't need to know the size of hash table beforehand. I just put anything I want into it. For example, in `Ruby`:

```rb
h = {}
10000000.times{ |i| h[i]=rand(10000) }
```

How can it do this?

Answer (score 5):

See [the *Dynamic resizing* section of the *Hash table* article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Dynamic_resizing).

The usual approach is to use the same logic as [a dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array): have some number of buckets and when there is too much items in the hash table, create a new hash table with a larger size and move all the items to the new hash table.

Also, depending on the type of hash table, this resizing might not be necessary for correctness (i.e. it would still work even without resizing), but it is certainly necessary for performance.

Comment: a nice rehashing approach is to double the size of the table, and then when you search for a value, you hash its key, and do a modulu search in your hash table starting with `hash % current_size`, then `hash % current_size/2`, etc. When you find the value, you can rehash it. That way you can do lazy rehashing without losing too much performance, because commonly accessed values get rehashed automatically.

Comment: @DvirVolk, lazy rehash is nice. You already know entry in top-most hash table and know where to instert from lower hash tables. But you might have situation when some entry will hold the whole table of empty buckets. That "Incremental resizing" from wiki is solution of tradoff speed for size of data as I understand (finally you hold 2*N buckets where N is size of top-most hash table). Doubling size is good for "copying all entries" by the fact that you have to split single buckets into two or merge two into one (without hash recalculation) with reusing linked-lists of old buckets.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I had this exact idea just now, but I am struggling to find a theoretical analysis of this technique, do you know of any?