# How to use hash tables when amount of slots is unknown?

Tags: data-structures, hashmap, hashtable

How do I use hash tables & chaining when the amount of slots required is yet unknown at usage? In other words I need to use the hash table before all keys and values for it are defined, how do I do this? I can't seem to figure it out since I assumed I'd need to know the amount of slots required in order to make a hash function to map the keys to those slots, but maybe I did not quite get the idea right of a hash table.

If anyone could help me out it'd be much appreciated!

Best regards,
Skyfe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement a dynamic-size hash table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858751/how-to-implement-a-dynamic-size-hash-table)

Comment: The Java HashMap is capable of dynamic rehashing to accomodate growth and can be tuned with initial settings.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html for a disccusion of how it operates and http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html for its source code which includes comments on how it operates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do so is simply adopt the idea of [amortized dynamic arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Geometric_expansion_and_amortized_cost).

You decide on a few factors, say - an initial size, a maximal load, and a growth factor. As an example, you could use initial size = 100, maximal load = 0.5, and growth factor = 2.

If enough items are inserted, at some point you'll have more than 50 = 100 * 0.5 items. At this point you allocate an array of size 200 = initial size * growth factor = 100 * 2, redistribute the items, and erase the old array. Etc.

Two notes:

- In practice, you wouldn't want to mulitply exactly by a given growth factor, as you probably want the array length to be prime. So you multiply by the factor, find the nearest larger prime (which you should precompute).
- Shrinking is the same, but you should use different factors for hysteresis. See the above link.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to what you want:
[How to implement a dynamic-size hash table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858751/how-to-implement-a-dynamic-size-hash-table)

> The usual approach is to use the same logic as a dynamic array: have
>   some number of buckets and when there is too much items in the hash
>   table, create a new hash table with a larger size and move all the
>   items to the new hash table.